# Whoops, looks like something went wrong :(

Tags: laravel-5.6

I have upgraded my laravel project to 5.6 version and can't see info about the error. I only see a blank page with `Whoops, looks like something went wrong`: https.

[image]

Comment: Check your error logs in `storage/logs` as well as from your web server.

Comment: Please apply a proper header for your question. Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shame on me I forgot to enable debug `APP_DEBUG=true`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for my fresh Laravel installation version 5.6

first: rename  `.env.example` to `.env` or create `.env` file

second: Generate a key suing  php artisan key:generate

third: copy the key generated and past it the .env file 
ex: `APP_KEY=base64:H1HZa/**********`

lastly rerun `php artisan serve`